# What is the point of writing REST APIs but in Azure Functions?

Tags: c#, azure, api, azure-functions

I've just started following some Azure Function tutorials and digging into this more so I'm quite New to this and my question may seem very easy but I couldn't find any answer for it yet.

What is the point of creating REST APIs using Azure Functions?

I mean, if we need to have some APIs then why not using ASP.NET Core or ASP.NET Web API itself? Should we say that we only expose APIs with Azure Functions that takes care of lightweight operations? Or basically when of course we're not talking about building up a web application?

Because, my mindset was that we use Azure Functions instead of Background Processor, for example, we can replace a Windows Service with an Azure Function. But, now that I have seen this API feature with Azure Func, then I'm curious to find out what's the point of that in an actual commercial product?

Comment: There's a million reason you would choose one over the other, but most of them are opinion based I'm afraid.

Comment: But for starters... how hard is it for you to scale up/out a web app? Functions will do almost that by default.

Comment: @DavidG yes, agree with you. Basically, all of the advantages of Azure Funcs we would benefit from if we use them but still it doesn't convince me that much - maybe it's just strange to me as I'm new to this! don't really know..

Comment: Maybe this article will shed some lights: [Is Azure Functions over Web API Beneficial?](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/01/01/is-azure-functions-over-web-api-beneficial/)

Comment: This is a broad question. Read about serverless paradigm.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The two big reasons for using functions instead of running a web app are cost and scalability. If your API is getting constant traffic at the same level 24/7 then using a function is not going to be beneficial.

However, if your API is only really getting traffic for a few hours a day, then using a function is likely to save you money, as when no one is hitting it, or load is low, your costs will be very small. Similarly, if your API traffic is very spiking, and you could see large increases in load for short periods, then functions work well for this as they can scale quickly to meet the demand and then scale down again.

Answer (score 6):

I'd say because rest api is an ideal candidate for being a function. It doesnt need a UI, it just returns json (perfect for Azure Function). It doesnt have state (perfect for Azure Function). You invoke it only when you need it, its doesnt have to run always.

All of these combined makes for a nice Azure Function use case. But you dont have to follow this route.

Comment: thanks for this - it helps to get some clues. I can agree more with the two last reasons and not the first one as we can just create an API project without having any UI on it - even removing the default views that Visual Studio adds to the project. But, maybe if we're going to have a scenario within which out API consumers do not need to constantly access the APIs then we can choose the Funcs over the API projects so it can be more cost effective then

Comment: its kinda opinion based, I'm stating reasons why api is a valid use case for functions. I'm not insisting you should use it ;)

Comment: surely you're not - I'm trying to convince myself with that ;)